# Как анимировать высоты блока?

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, css-animation

Мне необходимо анимировать открытие/скрытие блока на подобии функций у **JQuery** `show()/hide()`.

Высота блока определяется, относительно внутреннего содержимого, по этому я не могу анимироваться высоту через `CSS: transition`. Был вариант через `JS` изменять высоту, но так как элемент скрыт, то его высота равно 0 (cвойство `offsetHeight`), и по этому я не могу за ранее сохранить размеры элемента в переменную, что бы потом их использовать.

**Пример на `jQuery`. Мне надо только уменьшение высоты.**

```js
$( "#click" ).click(function () {
 let elem = $("#elem");
 elem.toggleClass("open");
 elem.hasClass("open") ? elem.hide(1000) : elem.show(1000);
})
```

```css
.main {
  height: 200px;
  background: #542;
}

#click {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.height {
  height: 20px;
  background: #122;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>html-ready</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body class="page">
  <button id="click">Тронь меня</button>
  <main class="main" id="elem">
  </main>
  <div class="height">Првоерка высоты</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Мой кейс**

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
  function getElemClass(name) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(name);
  }

  function getElemId(name) {
    return document.getElementById(name);
  }
  //Acordeon

  function addManyEvents(name, event) {
    let elements = getElemClass(name);
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      let attributesList = {
        attribute: "date-anchor",
        class: "accordion-wrap__open"
      };

      elements[i].addEventListener(event, function(e) {
        let self = this;
        let elementsList = {
          daughterElem: getElemId(self.getAttribute(attributesList.attribute)),
          switchClass: getElemClass(attributesList.class)[0]
        };

        function containsClass(elem) {
          return elem.classList.contains(attributesList.class);
        }

        function toggleClass(elem) {
          return elem.classList.toggle(attributesList.class);
        }

        if (containsClass(elementsList.daughterElem)) {
          toggleClass(elementsList.daughterElem);
        } else if (elementsList.switchClass) {
          toggleClass(elementsList.switchClass);
          toggleClass(elementsList.daughterElem);
        } else {
          toggleClass(elementsList.daughterElem);
        }
      })
    }
  }

  addManyEvents("accordion-wrap__title", "click");
}())
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
p,
figure,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
ol,
dl,
li,
menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

input,
select {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.main {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: #023;
}

.accordion-wrap {
  background: #532;
  padding: 20px;
}

.accordion-wrap__head {
  background: #96952a;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #135671;
}

.accordion-wrap__title {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-wrap__body {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #135671;
  border-right: 2px solid #135671;
}

.accordion-wrap__open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>html-ready</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body class="page">
  <main class="main">
    <h1 class="title">Accordion</h1>
    <dl class="accordion-wrap">
      <dt class="accordion-wrap__head">
    <span class="accordion-wrap__title" date-anchor="accordion-body-1">First</span>
   </dt>
      <dd id="accordion-body-1" class="accordion-wrap__body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum maxime aliquam, voluptate odio iste. Recusandae quaerat quasi dolore libero, perspiciatis rem quae eos. Architecto placeat incidunt, neque corporis dignissimos</dd>
      <dt class="accordion-wrap__head">
    <span class="accordion-wrap__title" date-anchor="accordion-body-2">Second</span>
   </dt>
      <dd id="accordion-body-2" class="accordion-wrap__body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum maxime aliquam, voluptate odio iste. Recusandae quaerat quasi dolore libero, perspiciatis rem quae eos. Architecto placeat incidunt, neque corporis dignissimos</dd>
      <dt class="accordion-wrap__head">
    <span class="accordion-wrap__title" date-anchor="accordion-body-3">Thirst</span>
   </dt>
      <dd id="accordion-body-3" class="accordion-wrap__body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum maxime aliquam, voluptate odio iste. Recusandae quaerat quasi dolore libero, perspiciatis rem quae eos. Architecto placeat incidunt, neque corporis dignissimos</dd>
    </dl>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Альтернативная ссылка на пример: [Accordion](https://jsfiddle.net/Devinora/ouLbm83w/)

Comment: А почему бы не сделать в CSS `@keyframe` и вызывать его через JS при нажатии на объект(или при любом другом событии)?

Comment: Напишите свой аниматор на JS. Перед стартом сделайте `show`, посчитайте высоты, затем анимируйте от 0 до заданной  высоты, в конце задайте высоту `auto`. Пример в ответе к этому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174578/Как-запретить-проигрывать-вторую-анимацию-пока-не-закончилась-первая-и-наоборот/ .

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, можно через `transition` анимировать `max-height/min-height`, для этого не подойдет `display: none;`, но с помощью `max-height: 0; overflow: hidden;` можно имитировать.

Не уверен, что то что нужно, но как вариант:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('[data-js="spoilerToggle"]');
const spoilerToggle = e => {
  const spoiler = document.querySelector(`[data-js="spoiler"][data-targetId="${e.target.dataset.targetid}"]`);
  const spoilerContentHeight = spoiler.children[0].clientHeight;
  
  spoiler.style.maxHeight = `${spoilerContentHeight}px`;
  
  spoiler.classList.toggle('open');
  clearTimeout(animationTimeout);
  
  if (spoiler.classList.contains('open')) {
    animationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      spoiler.style.maxHeight = 'none';
    }, 1000);
  }
  else {
    animationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      spoiler.style.maxHeight = 0;
    }, 0);
  }
}
let animationTimeout = null;

button.addEventListener('click', spoilerToggle);
```

```css
.spoiler {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.spoiler__content {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button data-js="spoilerToggle" data-targetId="1">Toggle</button>
<div class="spoiler" data-js="spoiler" data-targetId="1">
  <div class="spoiler__content"><div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вместо `setTimeout`, можно использовать событие `transitionend`. Я знаю, что `max/min-height` анимируется, но дело в том, что высоту блока формирует внутренний контент, а не я пишу эту высоту. Можно схитрить, и анимировать через `min-height`, но проблема в том, что я не знаю какую именно высоту писать, а если написать больше, то часть анимации будет заморожена, ибо отчет будет идти от заданного значения.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, у `transitionend` с поддержкой все не очень хорошо. Неизвестность высоты контента учтена в данном решении, js задает высоту для `.spoiler` беря за основу высоту `.spoiler__content` (который скрыт), после завершения анимации задается `max-height: auto;` для адаптивности (по сути так же работает и `.hide`, `.show`, только добавляется ещё состояние `display: none;` и изменение ширины блока - но судя по поставленной задаче это не требуется).

Comment: ты видел мой контекст? получается, мне надо создать лишнюю обертку, что бы анимировать высоту? В твоем кейсе можно использовать обычный height, так как ты проценты не используешь, то она тоже будет анимироваться.