# Как запретить проигрывать вторую анимацию, пока не закончилась первая и наоборот? JS

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

При нажатии на кнопку выезжает `div`,
если нажать на эту кнопку два или больше раз
`div` начинает дергаться вправо и влево:

```js
'use strict';

let button = document.querySelector('button'),
  anBox = document.querySelector('#anima');

function animationl() {
  let pos = 100,
    id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--;
      anBox.style.right = pos + '%';
    }
  }
}

function animationr() {
  let pos = 0,
    id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      anBox.style.right = pos + '%';
    }
  }
}


button.addEventListener('click', function l() {
  animationl();
  button.removeEventListener('click', l);
  button.addEventListener('click', function r() {
    animationr();
    button.removeEventListener('click', r);
    button.addEventListener('click', l);
  });
});
```

```css
#anima {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  right: 100%;
}

.buy-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 65%;
  height: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(131, 60, 60);
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blanchedalmond;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.buy-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(218, 112, 112);
}

.buy-btn:active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="anima"></div>
<button class="buy-btn">BUY</button>
```

Не могу найти способ запретить проигрывать сразу две анимации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы анимация была плавной лучше делать ее с помощью `window.requestAnimationFrame`. В таком случае браузер оптимизирует перерисовку контента, обновляя элемент не через определенные интервалы времени (как в случае с setInterval), а каждый раз во время очередного обновления кадра, что делает анимацию плавной, с учетом частоты обновления кадров монитора. Это новый и современный подход к созданию анимаций.

```js
'use strict';

//******************************************************

function animate(duration, callbackStart, callbackStep, callbackEnd) {
  var starttime = null; 
  function step(timestamp) {
    if (!starttime) {
      starttime = timestamp;
    }
    var runtime = timestamp - starttime, 
        progress = runtime / duration;
    callbackStep(Math.max(0, Math.min(progress, 1)));  
    if (runtime < duration) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    } else {
      callbackEnd();
    }
  }
  callbackStart();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}  

//******************************************************

var button = document.querySelector('button'),
    anBox = document.querySelector('#anima');

var dir = false, // направление анимации (true = прямо, false = обратно)
  anima = false; // активность анимации (true = запущена, false = отключена)

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Проверяем не запущена ли уже анимация
  if (!anima) {
    // Меняем направление
    dir = !dir;
    // Анимация на 1000 милисекунд
    animate(1000, function start() {
      // Перед стартом анимации 
      anima = true;
      anBox.style.right = dir ? '100%' : '0%';
    }, function step(x) {
      // Во время анимации х меняется от 0 до 1
      anBox.style.right = 100 * (dir ? 1 - x : x) + '%';
    }, function end() {
      // После конца анимации
      anima = false;
      anBox.style.right = dir ? '0%' : '100%';
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#anima {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  right: 100%;
}

.buy-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 65%;
  height: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(131, 60, 60);
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blanchedalmond;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.buy-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(218, 112, 112);
}

.buy-btn:active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="anima"></div>
<button class="buy-btn">BUY</button>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо), это какая то отдельная библиотека? или все тот же javascript чистый

Comment: Это чистый JS. Работает во всех современных браузерах. А для более старых обычно применятся небольшой скрипт `rAF polyfill`, который эмулирует работу `requestAnimationFrame` посредством функции `setInterval`. То есть, если в старом браузере нет `requestAnimationFrame`, то будет использована конструкция с `setInterval`.

Answer (score 3):

Если с минимальным изменением кода, так:

```js
'use strict';

let button = document.querySelector('button'),
  anBox = document.querySelector('#anima');
  
  
let animating = false; // <--

function animationl() {
  animating = true; // <--
  
  let pos = 100, id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
      animating = false; // <--
    } else {
      pos--;
      anBox.style.right = pos + '%';
    }
  }
}

function animationr() {
  animating = true; // <--
  
  let pos = 0, id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      animating = false; // <--
    } else {
      pos++;
      anBox.style.right = pos + '%';
    }
  }
}

let curr_fn = animationr;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (animating) return; // <-- return
  
  curr_fn = (curr_fn == animationl) ? animationr : animationl;
  // Переключает текущую функцию, кторую следуют запустить.
  
  curr_fn();
});
```

```css
#anima {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  right: 100%;
}

.buy-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 65%;
  height: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(131, 60, 60);
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blanchedalmond;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.buy-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(218, 112, 112);
}

.buy-btn:active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="anima"></div>
<button class="buy-btn">BUY</button>
```

Завести внешнюю переменную `let animating = false;` вначале каждой анимации сделать её true и при клике, `if (animating) return;`

Но вообще-то можно переложить логику анимации на CSS `transition: 0.5s linear;` а при клике только переключать необходимое финальное значение:

```js
'use strict';

let button = document.querySelector('button');
let box = document.querySelector('#anima');

let value = 100;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  value = (value === 0) ? 100 : 0;
  
  box.style.right = value + "%";
});
```

```css
#anima {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  right: 100%;
  
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}

.buy-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 65%;
  height: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(131, 60, 60);
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blanchedalmond;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.buy-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(218, 112, 112);
}

.buy-btn:active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="anima"></div>
<button class="buy-btn">BUY</button>
```